# Verilog can't figure out why a reg is always X

Tags: verilog, fpga, waveform

I am trying to do a VGA output using verilog but I can't seem to figure out why r_hcount stays X. The simulation waveforms show that r_vcount is being reset to 0 properly but for some reason r_hcount never gets reset to 0. I can't figure out why...

Verilog code:

```
module m_VGA640x480(
  input  wire        iw_clock,
  input  wire        iw_pix_stb,
  input  wire        iw_rst,
  output wire        ow_hs,
  output wire        ow_vs,
  output wire        ow_blanking,
  output wire        ow_active,
  output wire        ow_screenend,
  output wire        ow_animate,
  output wire  [9:0] ow_x,
  output wire  [9:0] ow_y
  );
  localparam HS_STA = 16;
  localparam HS_END = 16 + 96;
  localparam HA_STA = 16 + 96 + 48;
  localparam VS_STA = 480 + 11;
  localparam VS_END = 400 + 11 + 2;
  localparam VA_END = 480;
  localparam LINE   = 800;
  localparam SCREEN = 524;

  reg [9:0] r_hcount;
  reg [9:0] r_vcount;

  assign ow_hs = ~((r_hcount >= HS_STA) & (r_hcount < HS_END));
  assign ow_vs = ~((r_vcount >= VS_STA) & (r_vcount < VS_END));

  assign ow_x = (r_hcount <  HA_STA) ? 0 : (r_hcount - HA_STA);
  assign ow_y = (r_vcount >= VA_END) ? (VA_END - 1) : (r_vcount);

  assign ow_blanking = ((r_hcount < HA_STA) | (r_vcount > VA_END - 1));

  assign ow_active = ~((r_hcount < HA_STA) | (r_vcount > VA_END - 1));

  assign ow_screenend = ((r_vcount == SCREEN - 1) & (r_hcount == LINE));

  assign ow_animate = ((r_vcount ==VA_END - 1) & (r_hcount == LINE));

  always @(posedge iw_clock)
  begin
    if (iw_rst)
    begin
      r_hcount <= 0;
      r_vcount <= 0;
    end
    if (iw_pix_stb)
    begin
      if (r_hcount == LINE)
      begin
        r_hcount <= 0;
        r_vcount <= r_vcount + 1;
      end
      else
        r_hcount <= r_hcount + 1;

      if (r_vcount == SCREEN)
        r_vcount <= 0;
    end
  end
endmodule
```

Here is the result of the simulation. r_hcount is bugged... The code is supposed to set both counters to 0 when reset is 1 but for some reason it's not getting reset to 0. Please help.

[Wavefrorm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bdsL2.png)

Comment: After tinkering a bit more with the code, I found out that it was because `r_hcount <= 0` was getting overridden by `r_hcount <= r_hcount + 1` which will set r_hcount to X. This was caused because the two clock inputs were both the same frequency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your work, I notice one point may cause the issue

```
always @(posedge iw_clock)
begin
    if (iw_rst)
    //you define r_hcount <= 0 here
    .....
    if (iw_pix_stb) //<== another condition
    // r_hcount <= 0 is also defined here
```

So if posedge clock happened, `r_hcount` may be bugged here.
I suggest it should be done like this

```
 else if (iw_pix_stb) <=== else if here
```

Good luck.

Comment: Yes. That was exactly it. I should have realized it earlier. Thank you very much!

Comment: @funnypig run For a very long time I don't touch Verilog code. And I still get it muahahaha, have fun coding :)

Comment: Thank you. I'm still new to verilog so I still make silly mistakes. Hopefully, I'll be much better at it by the end of my current project.

Answer (score 0):

After tinkering a bit more with the code, I found out that it was because r_hcount <= 0 was getting overridden by r_hcount <= r_hcount + 1 which will set r_hcount to X. This was caused because the two clock inputs were both the same frequency.

I should be more careful in the future...